# VB .Net And Crystal reports dataconnection: 'Number of invalid table'

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

When you run the code, the following error occurs: 'Number of invalid table'.

Can anyone tell me why?

Does anyone have any example that can help me?

I need to know how to pass the address and password of a database of acces to the report and subreport.

```
        RptDocument.Load("c:\ContDeta.rpt", CrystalDecisions.Shared.OpenReportMethod.OpenReportByDefault)

        Dim CTableLogInfo As CrystalDecisions.Shared.TableLogOnInfo
        Dim ConnInfo As CrystalDecisions.Shared.ConnectionInfo = New CrystalDecisions.Shared.ConnectionInfo()

        ConnInfo.Type = CrystalDecisions.Shared.ConnectionInfoType.CRQE
        ConnInfo.ServerName = String.Empty
        ConnInfo.DatabaseName = "c:\5354Tmp_Contadores.mdb"
        ConnInfo.Password = Chr(10) & "5354"
        ConnInfo.AllowCustomConnection = False
        ConnInfo.IntegratedSecurity = False

        For Each CTable As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table In RptDocument.Database.Tables
            CTable.LogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo = ConnInfo
            CTableLogInfo = CTable.LogOnInfo
            CTableLogInfo.ReportName = "ContDeta.rpt"
            CTableLogInfo.TableName = CTable.Name
            CTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(CTableLogInfo)
        Next

        For Each CTable As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table In RptDocument.Subreports("Cabecera.rpt").Database.Tables()
            CTable.LogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo = ConnInfo
            CTableLogInfo = CTable.LogOnInfo
            CTableLogInfo.ReportName = "Cabecera.rpt"
            CTableLogInfo.TableName = CTable.Name
            CTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(CTableLogInfo)
        Next

        For Each CTable As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table In RptDocument.Subreports("Selecciones.rpt").Database.Tables()
            CTable.LogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo = ConnInfo
            CTableLogInfo = CTable.LogOnInfo
            CTableLogInfo.ReportName = "Selecciones.rpt"
            CTableLogInfo.TableName = CTable.Name
            CTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(CTableLogInfo)
        Next

        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = RptDocument
```